# Erro de MismatchSenderId

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, push-notification

Tinha vários projetos em meu console. Consegui fazer recebimento de push notification(PN). Então dropei todos os projetos e criei apenas um. Fiz uma App baseada no passo a passo que um colega me passou e não consegui receber. Peguei o App que estava funcionando, e coloquei nesse mesmo projeto recem criado no console do firebase. Bem, acontece que quando eu pelo meu programa de envio de PN, quando faço uma nova PN, me dá erro de:

> MismatchSenderId

O mais interessante é que quando eu dei o primeiro start na aplicação, uma PN foi enviada, mas não por mim, como se estivesse presa e ao startar ela veio, mas foi só. Depois não deu mais mensagem alguma, dando esse erro. Estou debugando pra ver o que pode ser e acho que deve ser a mesma coisa que está impedindo de eu receber a PN por essa nova abordagem que eu estou fazendo.

**EDIT1**

Meu Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.global.autorizador.br" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionName="Spike">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="Autorizador.Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon">    

        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" 
              android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" 
              android:exported="true" 
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Esse App estava funcionando e recebendo PN

**EDIT2**

Esse é o código para envio de PN

```
public static async Task<IFCMResponse> SenderMessage()
        {
            FCMClient client = new FCMClient("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); //as derived from https://console.firebase.google.com/project/
            var message = new Message()
            {
                To = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY", //topic example /topics/all
                Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                {
                    Body = "Solicitação de Novo Desconto",
                    Title = "Desconto",
                }
            };
            var result = await client.SendMessageAsync(message);
            return result;
        }
```

O que posso garantir é que **FCMClient** está recebendo a chave do servidor do corrente projeto e **Message** está recebendo o token, no momento em que o App é iniciado. Como eu faço? Coloco um break onde é registrado, pego esse token e colo na aplicação **Sender**. E quando eu envio a mensagem, coloco um break em **return result** e lá eu vejo o erro de **MismatchSenderId**. O que pode estar incorreto seria o projeto no **firebase**, mas eu vi a **URL** e está **OK** e dentro do projeto tem aqueles valores gerados por ele(projeto) e acho que estão corretos também.

O que eu achei estranho é que esse pedaço no **google-services.json** estava desse jeito

```
"api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyCHqktEMu9xPGHnXpEXWwRpimBRgzv-MHU" 
        }
      ]
```

e como a chave de api da web do servidor era outra, mudei para a chave que estava no servidor. Isso já é suficiente para dizer que algo está errado, pois quando chegamos ao ponto de alterar algo gerado automaticamente, é problema.

```
"api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyB2iXNmbPjvwZqDNubYX2Sy6QMsMJmw3N4" 
        }
      ]
```

Não sei se fiz certo, não tenho certeza se a chave utilizada em **current_key** é a mesma **chave de api da web**

**EDIT3**

Lendo na internet assuntos correlacionados, descobri que o SenderID que a aplicação está rodando, não é o mesmo que está no projeto. Como isso acontece e como se resolve isso?
Esse é o que a aplicação está carregando:

**857564901519**

e esse é o do projeto que está sendo apontado pelo programa que envia as PN

**903763617329**

Comment: O que achei estranho é nesse projeto eu tenho dois App's. Mas quando gero o **google-services.json** ele aponta sempre para o mesmo App, o mesmo **Package Name** e alterei amnualmente e acho que foi isso que zoou tudo.

Comment: O problema é que o SenderID é uma constante. Como antes estava setado para um projeto, ele estava trazendo o valor anterior do SenderID. Setei para o valor atual e está ok. Olhei esse código todo, menos as constantes. Claro, uma baita falha minha.